# SQL Server custom sort while grouping by max sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, custom-sort

I have 3 columns (`Year, Number, SUM(Amount)`) and I am trying to sort them by the max sum of amount.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    YEAR(period) AS [Year], id_number, 
    SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0)) AS [Amount]
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(period), id_number
ORDER BY 
    SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0)) DESC, id_number, YEAR
```

This is not the sorting I'm trying to achieve. I'd like to group them together by their id_number but sort by the max amount for all years returned. I'm guessing I might have to write a case statement but I haven't figured it out yet. I Will update if I do. I wanted to ask for help also before I rack my mind for hours on this one.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you able to share example of desired output as that sql query looks ok to me.

Comment: `WHERE (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)` don't use syntax like this; it's not SARGable. Use *proper* date logic: `WHERE period >= '20100101' AND period < '20210101'`

Comment: So you want the groups (as denoted by id_number) to be sorted by the max value of the sums, not the individual rows.

Comment: Yes. I have to think out loud sometimes and my solution might be cumbersome but I have it working now and am trying everyone's suggestions here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based in your description, you want to sort the *ids* by the maximum sum in *any year*.  If that is the case, use window functions in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 YEAR(period) AS [Year], id_number, 
       SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0)) AS [Amount]
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021
GROUP BY YEAR(period), id_number
ORDER BY MAX(SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY id_number),
         id_number, YEAR;
```

The second sort key is needed so all rows for a given `id_number()` are together when there are ties.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be sufficient for you. Just wrap it in a subquery and youre good to go

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1000 
            YEAR(period) AS [Year], id_number, 
            SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0)) AS [Amount]
        FROM 
            table
        WHERE 
            (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)
        GROUP BY 
            YEAR(period), id_number
    ) x
ORDER BY 
    MAX(ISNULL(amount, 0)) DESC, id_number, YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the column by index like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    YEAR(period) AS [Year], id_number, 
    SUM(ISNULL(amount, 0)) AS [Amount]
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(period), id_number
ORDER BY 
    3 DESC, id_number, YEAR
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Simply swapping the expression and the associated ordinal does not change the logic of the original query.

Comment: Ordinal, that would be the same as calling the column right?

Comment: Since the ORDER BY is processed after the SELECT - it is one of the places where you can reference the alias of the column.  Example: ORDER BY [Amount] DESC

Comment: No, @MichaelBrown . `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY Col3;` and `SELECT Col1, Col3 FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY Col3;` would both work, replace `ORDER BY Col3` with `ORDER BY 3`, however, and the latter query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you much @Doug, I'm going to run that down and try it out.
I also came up with a solution that might be a bit nutty but it works. LOL.

```
SELECT t2.row, YEAR(period) AS [Year], t1.id_number, SUM(ISNULL(amount,0)) AS [Consumption]
FROM table t1 JOIN 
(SELECT id_number, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SUM(ISNULL(amount,0))desc) as row
FROM table
WHERE (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)
GROUP BY id_number) t2 ON t1.id_number = t2.id_number
WHERE (YEAR(period) >= 2010 AND YEAR(period) < 2021)
GROUP BY t2.row, YEAR(period), t1.id_number
ORDER BY t2.row, year
```

@Larnu, I will look at fixing this. Thank you.